# Duplicate PackageNames while running getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);

Tags: android, usage-statistics

I'm trying to get the Foreground Time each activity was alive in my Android Phone.

The Code I execute is as follows

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public List<UsageStats> getUsageStats() {
        UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats = mUsageStatsManager
                .queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis());


        return queryUsageStats;
    }
```

And this is the print Statement

```
for(UsageStats usageStats:getUsageStats()){
    Log.i("Usage Stats",usageStats.toString()+"\t"+usageStats.getPackageName()+"\t"+usageStats.getTotalTimeInForeground());
}
```

And the result I get is as follows.

```
com.whatsapp    2413684
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox 2344707
com.google.android.youtube      1786804
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox 1683449
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox 1577473
com.whatsapp    1040572
```

As you can whatsapp and google Search box are there twice, and have different foreground time.

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting it twice, and is there a way so that I get only the Amount of time the activity was in ForeGround.

Answer (score 2):

When running the command:

```
adb shell "ps -x | grep google"
```

I get the following output (truncated):

```
u0_a22    1977  1267  1480140 46296    ep_poll 0000000000 S com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor (u:2, s:7)
u0_a22    2115  1267  1895332 210352    ep_poll 0000000000 S com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search (u:1866, s:7987)
```

That means that the `googlequicksearchbox` application is running in two different processes (diffrentiated by the process name and PID).

The time you get is for foreground processes. What this means is described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle). That does not only mean these are Activities.

Generally there is no other way to get the time, when the app was opened in a simple way. That is because, applications can have activities, services, constant notifications shown. All of this is may affect user experience. Consider Facebook Chat Heads. They may be in the corner of the screen, visible to user, but another application is opened (one of it's activities is after `onResume` event). But Facebook is running in foreground, the uses sees it. So there are at least 2 running apps in foreground.

The solution is just to sum up the results if the package name is quite the same. Or another way is to run constant service in background, checking running application once a while. But that is a more time consuming and labor intensive solution.

Comment: makes sense to me!